# Create an image and write in it a text with Jimp (Node js)

Tags: node.js, image, text

I'm starting with node and I've written this program without success. I intend to create an image with dimensions with a color, write text in the image and then save to a file. The program does everything except the text. What am I doing wrong?

```
let Jimp = require('jimp');

let image = new Jimp(300, 530, 'green', (err, image) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});

let message = 'Hello!';
let x = 10;
let y = 10;
let maxWidth = 300;

Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_8_BLACK)
    .then(font => {
        image.print(font, x, y, message);
    });

let file = 'new_name' + '.' + image.getExtension();
```

Comment: Looks OK to me, is the font just too small? Try `Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @barro32 may be correct.  I added some code to write out the image and it seems to work:

```
let Jimp = require('jimp')

let image = new Jimp(300, 530, 'green', (err, image) => {
  if (err) throw err
})

let message = 'Hello!'
let x = 10
let y = 10

Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK)
  .then(font => {
    image.print(font, x, y, message)
    return image
  }).then(image => {
    let file = `new_name.${image.getExtension()}`
    return image.write(file) // save
  })
```

The result was:

[image: new_name.png]

Comment: Even I am intrigued by why my code lines do not work. But your code works and I can continue.

Answer (score 2):

The code to write the text must be INSIDE the callback, otherwise it may run before the image is actually created.